# How to integrate cisco-DNA with my existing spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, cisco

I have cisco DNA in one instance, as per my use-case i want to access the api's provided by cisco DNA from my spring-boot application. Kindly let me know what can be the possible ways to integrate that.